# Bug in tkz-euclide? \tkzInterLL(S1,S2)(L,K) not working when points are defined by \tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=1,D=2) \tkzGetPoint{K}

Tags: tkz-euclide

I've made this exercise to find the intersection point between a line and a plane.

[image]

With this code:

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usepackage{pgf,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymax=7,xmax=9]
\tkzDefPoints{1/0/A, 6/0/B, 6/5/C, 1/5/D}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](30:2.5){E};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[B](30:2.5){F};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[C](30:2.5){G};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[D](30:2.5){H};

%%bepalen van lijstuk [ST]    
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=1,D=2) \tkzGetPoint{K};
\tkzDrawPoints(K)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](K)
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(E=1,F=-2.5) \tkzGetPoint{L};
\tkzDrawPoints(L)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](L)

\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,D D,A F,G G,H B,F D,H C,G K,L);
\tkzDrawSegments[dashed](A,E E,F E,H F,L);
\tkzDrawPolygon[fill=orange!40, opacity=.4](B,C,G,F);
%\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H);
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C,D,G,H);
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B,E,F);  \pause

%%% tekenen van het hulpvlak
\tkzDrawPolygon[color=green,thick](A,D,L); \pause
\tkzDefShiftPoint[L](90:5){K};
\tkzDrawPolygon[fill=green,opacity=0.1,thick](A,D,K,L); \pause

%%% tekenen van de snijlijn
\tkzInterLL(C,G)(D,K)  \tkzGetPoint{S1};
\tkzInterLL(A,L)(B,F)  \tkzGetPoint{S2};
\tkzDrawPoint[color=red,size=8,fill=red](S1);
\tkzLabelPoint[color=red,above](S1) {S$_1$}; \pause
\tkzDrawPoint[color=red,size=8,fill=red](S2);
\tkzLabelPoint[color=red,below](S2) {S$_2$}; \pause
\tkzDrawSegment[color=red,thick](S1,S2) \pause
\tkzInterLL(S1,S2)(L,D)  \tkzGetPoint{S} %%%% <<<< this works fine, but is not correct
%\tkzInterLL(S1,S2)(L,K)  \tkzGetPoint{S} %%%% <<<< this doesn't work fine, but is correct
\tkzDrawPoint[color=red,size=10,fill=red](S)
\tkzLabelPoints[color=red,right](S) 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As you can read in my code, the intersection between `KL` and `S1S2` is not working. I've tested every other point (H,G,D,C,...) but the only thing that doesn't work is using KL. Strange enough but K and L are defined by

```
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=1,D=2) \tkzGetPoint{K};

\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(E=1,F=-2.5) \tkzGetPoint{L};
```

I could define point `K` in a simple way, but I want to know why this is not working. (the error file says `FP error: Division by zero!.`, makes no sense to me?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you redefine `K` by `\tkzDefShiftPoint[L](90:5){K};` and so the lines `(K,L)` and `(S1,S2)` are parallel, so `\tkzInterLL(S1,S2)(L,K)` is undefined.

Comment: Great! I overlooked my code 100 times, and didn't saw the fault :-( Thanks for solving the problem after 2 years! It is still useful

Comment: I was looking for a problem of my own `\tkzInterLL`, so I arrived to your question 2 years later ;)

Comment: Advise : always use `\tkzDrawPoints` at the end, so the points are drawn over the lines and you can see their "final" position.